# REST REQUEST not returning correct response

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, python-requests, django-filter

I'm fairly new to REST and have been working on using Requests (Python), with Django, and the Django Rest Framework. I am trying to make a get request which returns all objects with a "priority" (Int field) value of 4. The problem is the query doesn't seem to be working and the GET request is returning all project objects. The structure looks correct and I'm able to change the pages using the exact same syntax so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is everything I think you'd need, any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Generated URL = http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/projects/?priority=4

RestConnect.py{

```
local = 'http://localhost/'
base = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'


def sign_in(current_user, username, password):
        response = current_user.get(base + 'api-auth/login/', auth=(username, password))
        print response
        print response.url
        print response.reason

# Some of this is intentionally generic and a little rough (the way the session is being passed)
def find_priority(current_user, username, password):
    find_projects = {"priority": "4"}
    response = current_user.get(base + 'projects', params=find_projects,  auth=(username, password))
    print response
    print response.url
    print response.text
```

}

QueryTest.py {

```
import requests

import restconnect


current_user = requests.Session()

restconnect.sign_in(current_user, 'user', 'password')
restconnect.find_priority(current_user, 'user', 'password')
```

}

serializer.py {

```
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets
import django_filters

from . models import Project


class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'status', 'priority']


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project


class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    filter_class = ProjectFilter
```

}

Comment: Your views are missing, and those are where the filtering actually happens.

Comment: @KevinBrown I don't know how but the viewset was omitted when posting the question. I just included it. Sorry about that.